# I can't get data from EditTextView(email) after creating array list. It is totally fine if i directly insert data to object;

Tags: java, android

```
EditText mail=findViewById(R.id.editEmail);

String email=mail.getText().toString();
    
ArrayList<User> contacts=new ArrayList<>();

//contacts.add(new User("may","may@gmail.com"));//It totally fine with that

contacts.add(new User("may",email));//but not this

UserAdapter adapter=new UserAdapter(this);
adapter.setContacts(contacts);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,1));
```

I wish i could get data from editView instead of putting directly in obj

Comment: **Put these inside your button click listener**
``String email=mail.getText().toString();
contacts.add(new User("may",email));
// And Notify your adapter
``

Comment: Post the code for your `User` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Jim Rhodes. I could solve it per your codes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.